# Play movie from URL on Android

Tags: android, url, video, movie

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
```

But not successful. It's giving an error: "Cannot play this video"

Comment: What kind of video are you trying to play? mp4 or flv

Comment: Im successful. Thanks so much

Comment: please tell us the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you did not use

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Did you?