# Error in case playing video from a url

Tags: android, video

I'm trying to play a video from a URL, but I'm getting an error. I've tried different things but every time, an alert dialog pop up that says "can't play this video". Here is my code. Thanks

```
    String path = "http://tune.pk/video/3658227/alf-capitulo-19";

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);

    controller.setAnchorView(videoView);

    videoView.setMediaController(controller);

    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));

    videoView.start();
```

error in logcat

06-04 13:40:31.563: E/MediaPlayer(12565): error (1, -1004)

Comment: [play-movie-from-url-on-android?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277375/play-movie-from-url-on-android?rq=1)

Comment: I follow that link but the problem is still there. Now I tried web view instead of video view, it shows the video screen but on pressing play button it doesn't play video